# Foxpro 2.6 printing problem

Tags: printing, dos, foxpro

In my school days, i developed a hotel management system in legacy programming language foxpro 2.6. Few months ago, i revived the application and its running pretty well on windows xp. But, i am stuck at printing. Right now i am printing the page to a text file. Afterward i manually open the file and  call the print function on that.

I googled and found no effective tutorial or link or anything as to how can i get to print directly from foxpro 2.6. The printer is USB supported and i have tried the trick of adding another printer for virtual port LPT1 and then spooling. Nothing worked. 
Later i downloaded an application which acts as a spooler and sends any file that is added to the specified directory to Printer. Still, no success.

Can anyone help me with a short example, a link or a tutorial which guides me to the printing settings in foxpro 2.6

Thanks !!

Comment: Dude, there's no tutorial because foxpro 2.6 is 17 years old! I don't think it even works on OSs newer than Vista.

Comment: ya i know it doesnt work on vista and other OS .... But still XP is in use and we can run foxpro 2.6 on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the printer and share it. You may need to set permissions to allow Authenticated Users to use the printer.
Add NET USE LPT1: \CRAIG\USBPRINTER to the logon script for the user's profile.
For help on logon scripts, look up "To assign a logon script to a profile" in XP Help.

Answer (score 1):

Not true - it works perfectly well in Vista and Windows 7, as long as they are the 32-bit versions of those operating systems.

You might find the following useful. Disclaimer: I wrote it a long time ago.

[Painless Legacy FoxPro Applications On Modern Networks](http://www.hentzenwerke.com/catalog/painless.htm)

Comment: It's a paid solution. i have a single problem and it doesnt make sense to buy an entire book. My app is running well on XP and i am just stuck with the printing issue. I am just missing a minor setting that is it.... But thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Well, William's answer above is what you need. Basically the only reliable way to print is to an LPT port.